# String index out of range in Java

Tags: java

I am aware there are multiple threads like my assignment below, but I just can't figure it out. I can't exactly figure out the mistake. Help would be appreciated.

I am trying to do this program:

[image]

[image]

Everything works fine unless I input the same chains or similar (for example ACTG and ACTG or ACTG and ACTGCCCC), when it tells me

> string index out of range

This is that part of my code:

```
int tries=0;
int pos=-1;
int k;

for (int i=0; i<longDNA.length(); i++) {

    tries=0;
    k=i;

    for (int j=0; j<shortDNA.length(); j++) {

        char s=shortDNA.charAt(j);
        char l=longDNA.charAt(k);

        if (canConnect(s,l)) {
            tries+=1;
            k+=1;
        } 
    }

    if (tries==shortDNA.length()-1) {
        pos=i-1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in this if sentence: ' if (canConnect(s,l)) {
                tries+=1;
                k+=1;
            } ' Why are you incrementing k here when above you have set it to be equal to i? There will be a point when this line ' char l=longDNA.charAt(k)' will throw an error because it can't access character at kth position. I should tell you that I myself have not tested the code. But that's where the problem lies it seems

Comment: Actually just now I understood the question. Let me see what's the problem.

Comment: Surely the easiest way to do this is to flip the symbol of the "to attach" string to its complement, and then just call indexof that string in the longer string?

Comment: Thank you both for your help! @AndyTurner forgive me for not quite understanding what you mean? I am very new at JAVA and also a foreign student so I might need some more help, truly sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Dimi I am sorry my friend I tried to work on it personally but I couldn't do it. I don't know why professors give such a hard problem in homeworks.

Comment: Of course, don't worry about it. Thank you very much for trying!

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the two DNA strings `longer` and `shorter`. In order for `shorter` to attach somewhere on `longer`, a sequence of bases complementary to `shorter` must be found somewhere in `longer`, e.g. if there is `ACGT` in `shorter`, then you need to find `TGCA` somewhere in `longer`.

So, if you take `shorter` and flip all of its bases to their complements:

```
char[] cs = shorter.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; ++i) {
  // getComplement changes A->T, C->G, G->C, T->A,
  // and throws an exception in all other cases
  cs[i] = getComplement(cs[i]);
}
String shorterComplement = new String(cs);
```

For the examples given in your question, the complement of `TTGCC` is `AACGG`, and the complement of `TGC` is `ACG`.

Then all you have to do is to find `shorterComplement` within `longer`. You can do this trivially using `indexOf`:

```
return longer.indexOf(shorterComplement);
```

Of course, if the point of the exercise is to learn how to do string matching, you can look at well-known algorithms for doing the equivalent of `indexOf`. For instance, Wikipedia has a category for [String matching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_matching_algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your full code as fast as I could, I'm not sure if I fixed the problem but you don't get any errors.

Please try it and see if it works.
I hope you get this in time and good luck!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DNA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(findFirstMatchingPosition("ACTG", "ACTG"));
    }
    public static int findFirstMatchingPosition(String shortDNA, String longDNA) {
        int positionInLong = 0;
        int positionInShort;

        while (positionInLong < longDNA.length()) {
            positionInShort = 0;
            while(positionInShort < shortDNA.length()) {
                String s = shortDNA.substring(positionInShort, positionInShort + 1);
                if(positionInShort + positionInLong + 1 > longDNA.length()) {
                    break;
                }
                String l = longDNA.substring(positionInShort + positionInLong, positionInShort + positionInLong + 1);
                if(canConnect(s, l)) {
                    positionInShort++;
                    if(positionInShort == shortDNA.length()) {
                        return positionInLong;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            positionInLong++;
            if(positionInLong == longDNA.length()) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static String[] connections = {
            "AT",
            "TA",
            "GC",
            "CG"
    };
    private static boolean canConnect(String s, String l) {
        if(Arrays.asList(connections).contains((s+l).toUpperCase())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dimi No problem! I was as fast as I could but I ended up answering it a total of 3 minutes before it was due so it probably was not very useful. (Sorry about that!) Also, what Andy Turner was trying to say I think was that you could convert the `shortDNA` string into the opposite form (ATGC -> TACG for example), and then use `longDNA.indexOf()` to find where that string first showed up. It would also be very elegant as if it did not match, `indexOf()` would automatically return -1, which is what the problem requested. Anyway, glad to see you got it in on time!

Answer (score 0):

I finally changed something with the k as Faraz had mentioned above to make sure the charAt does not get used when k overrides the length of the string and the program worked marvelously!

The code was changed to the following:

```
int tries=0;
    int pos=-1;
    int k;

    for (int i=0; i<longDNA.length(); i++) {

        tries=0;
        k=i;

        for (int j=0; j<shortDNA.length(); j++) {

            if (k<longDNA.length()) {

                char s=shortDNA.charAt(j);
                char l=longDNA.charAt(k);


                if ((s=='A' && l=='T') || (s=='T' && l=='A') || (s=='G' && l=='C') || (s=='C' && l=='G')) {
                    tries+=1;
                    k+=1;
                } 

            }
        }

        if (tries==shortDNA.length()) {
                pos=i;
                break;
        }

    }
```

I am not sure how aesthetically pleasing or correct this excerpt is but - it completely solved my problem, and just 2 minutes before the deadline! :)

A huge thanks to all of you for spending some time to help me!!