# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 (Works with another program)

Tags: java, string

I'm supposed to create a program that finds the longest palindrome in a DNA string. Unlike a regular palindrome program, this one requires A to match with T and C to match with G (so instead of 1221 we'd have TCGA for example). After trying myself I did find a very good program for the normal palindrome problem, the one on this website:
http://www.journaldev.com/530/java-program-to-find-out-longest-palindrome-in-a-string

I then tried to modify it to fit my needs. Basically the changes I made were the following:

1. Instead of those strings shown in the example, I read a string from the argument line. The string is the following DNA sequence (although I tested the program with only parts of it):

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/genomeVirus.txt

2. Instead of the command

   ```
    while (left >= 0 && right < s.length()
               && s.charAt(left) == s.charAt(right)) {
           left--;
           right++;
       }
   ```

I did:

```
while (left >= 0 && right < s.length()
&& s.charAt(left) == 'A' && s.charAt(right) == 'T' || s.charAt(left) == 'T' && s.charAt(right) == 'A'
|| s.charAt(left) == 'G' && s.charAt(right) == 'C' || s.charAt(left) == 'C' && s.charAt(right) == 'G')
   {
 left--;
 right++;
```

(Full code below)

However, when I try this program on a string, I always get the error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at LongestPalindrome.intermediatePalindrome(LongestPalindrome.java:17)
    at LongestPalindrome.longestPalindromeString(LongestPalindrome.java:26)
    at LongestPalindrome.main(LongestPalindrome.java:5)
```

I just don't get it! I don't realize how I'm getting out of the string, when I try the original program I linked to, it always works with no matter which string. I feel like I'm doing everything correctly, simply replacing the == command with various scenarios that should make sense.

I figured it might have something to do with

```
return s.substring(left+1, right);"
```

I tried to take the +1 away but it seems to ruin the whole deal. I just don't realize how I'm going out of the string, since it worked perfectly before my adjustments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Below is the code!

```
public class LongestPalindrome {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   String gen = new String(args[0]);
   System.out.println(longestPalindromeString(gen));
 }

 static public String intermediatePalindrome(String s, int left, int right)     {
  if (left > right) return null;
  while (left >= 0 && right < s.length()
    && s.charAt(left) == 'A' && s.charAt(right) == 'T' || s.charAt(left) == 'T' && s.charAt(right) == 'A'
|| s.charAt(left) == 'G' && s.charAt(right) == 'C' || s.charAt(left) == 'C' && s.charAt(right) == 'G')
       {
   left--;
   right++;
  }
  return s.substring(left+1, right);
 }

 // O(n^2)
 public static String longestPalindromeString(String s) {
  if (s == null) return null;
  String longest = s.substring(0, 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
   //odd cases like 121
   String palindrome = intermediatePalindrome(s, i, i);
    if (palindrome.length() > longest.length()) {
    longest = palindrome;
   }
   //even cases like 1221
   palindrome = intermediatePalindrome(s, i, i + 1);
   if (palindrome.length() > longest.length()) {
    longest = palindrome;
   }
  }
  return longest;
 }

}
```

Comment: What input string are you giving it when it fails?

Comment: BTW: in `String gen = new String(args[0]);`, the `new String` isn't necessary. `String gen = args[0];` is sufficient.

Comment: Coincidence. Similar question [was just asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476020/get-odd-length-palindrome) with Python tag...

Comment: `&&` is evaluated before `||`, so the shortcut does not happen, and the index out of bounds happens. put your comparison condition in parenthesis

Comment: (basically if `left == -1`, `s.charAt(left) == 'T'` is still executed)

Comment: You should return `""` from `intermediatePalindrome` in the `left > right` case, to avoid a `NullPointerException` in `longestPalindromeString`.

Comment: @nbrooks no. What if the input string is `AAAA` - that's not a "palindrome" in the sense required here. It needs to be `AATT`, or something like that, so the first A is matched by the last T; it can't be matched with an A.

Comment: @nbrooks well I don't have a genetics background either; but I can see that OP is looking for complementary base pairs (A only matches T; C only matches G).

Comment: @nbrooks but - you can do this: reverse the string, change every A to a T, change every T to an A, C->G, G->C (note, this is not simply replacing, it's swapping). Then you can look for the longest common subsequence.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah if that's what's needed what I proposed wouldn't work. Seemed as if the solution was being made unnecessarily complicated, but looks like I oversimplified. You're right that reversing and inverting the string could lead to an interesting solution though.

Comment: @nbrooks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106644/string-index-out-of-range-in-java/35113126#35113126 I knew I'd thought about this before...

Comment: @AndyTurner That looks like a genetics background to me... `;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are calling it with `right == 0`. You need to change the first call to:

   ```
    String palindrome = intermediatePalindrome(s, i, i+1)
   ```
2. Operator precedence problem. You've added some || conditions which are also evaluated even if the range checks fail. It should be:

   ```
   while (left >= 0 && right < s.length()
   && (s.charAt(left) == 'A' && s.charAt(right) == 'T'
       || s.charAt(left) == 'T' && s.charAt(right) == 'A'
       || s.charAt(left) == 'G' && s.charAt(right) == 'C'
       || s.charAt(left) == 'C' && s.charAt(right) == 'G'))
   ```

Note the parentheses around the entire second operand of the second &&.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I did try to change the parentheses but the problem persisted, so I went back to the way they were originally. But even if you're right, I still get the same error with the parentheses modified as you did them, which is a shame.

Comment: It looks like you edited your response although I'm not sure. Again, thanks a lot but it still didn't work unfortunately. Did it work when you ran it? Again, I really appreciate your help, I don't know why the problem persists (I'm using DrJava like a noob, but same error occurs in Java Visualizer).

Comment: I only reformatted, no code change. You must have not copied it correctly.

Comment: Oh right, I'm sorry. Anyways, I tried it with your code and I still got the error, unfortunately. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: I swear, I've tried it so many times. The only change I've made to my code is to put your while loop instead of the original. I've copied it numerous times.

Comment: you're a genius EJP. Maybe I missed the first one, to change the palindrome string and add +1.. thanks a lot, greatly appreciated!!